# How do I query Prometheus for the timeseries that was updated last?

Tags: concurrency, prometheus

I have 100 instances of a service that use one database. I want them to export a Prometheus metric with the number of rows in a specific table of this database.

To avoid hitting the database with 100 queries at the same time, I periodically elect one of the instances to do the measurement and set a Prometheus gauge to the number obtained. Different instances may be elected at different times. Thus, each of the 100 instances may have its own value of the gauge, but only one of them is “current” at any given time.

**What is the best way** to pick only this “current” value from the 100 gauges?

My first idea was to export two gauges from each instance: the actual measurement and its timestamp. Then perhaps I could take the `max(timestamp)`, then `and` it with the actual metric. But I can’t figure out how to do this in PromQL, because `max` will erase the `instance` I could `and on`.

My second idea was to reset the gauge to −1 (some sentinel value) at some time after the measurement. But this looks brittle, because if I don’t synchronize everything tightly, the “current” gauge could be reset before or after the “new” one is set, causing gaps or overlaps. Similar considerations go for explicitly [deleting](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#MetricVec.Delete) the metric and for exporting it [with an explicit timestamp](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#NewMetricWithTimestamp) (to induce staleness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the first idea (not tested yet):

```
avg(my_rows_count and on(instance) topk(1, my_rows_count_timestamp))
```

`avg` could as well be `max` or `min`, it only serves to erase `instance` from the final result.

Comment: This looks like a good solution. `topk` may be also replaced with `max`.
However, did you think about measuring the number of rows by only one application always? Let's call it a sidecar and run next to the database. The only purpose of the sidecar would be to track the most important metrics and expose it to Prometheus.

Comment: @hagen1778, I don’t think `max` will work, because its output won’t have the `instance` label.

Comment: Yes, the “sidecar” is actually our default solution for this problem, and it’s likely I will stick to it, I was just thinking if I can come up with a nicer one. Thanks for the idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[last_over_time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) should do the trick

`last_over_time(my_rows_count[1m])`

given only one of them is “current” at any given time, like you said.

Comment: Only one of them is “current” _conceptually_ — the one that I updated last. The problem is that Prometheus doesn’t know that. It sees each of the 100 gauges on each scrape.

Comment: ah, so all 100 instances are scraped, only one of them has the "current" value, along with the latest `timestamp` label value, I suppose?